# Singleton but with a Twisted Public constructor

Tags: c++, singleton

I recently came across something similar in my code reviews.

```
/* A.h */

class A {
    enum Priv {
        k1,
    };
    
    public:
    A(Priv);
    static A& getInstance();
};
```

and...

```
/* A.cpp */

A::A(Priv) {}

/* static */
A& A::getInstance() {
    static auto instance = A(Priv::k1);
    return instance;
}
```

Things work, but why go the stretch of having a public constructor for `A` which can never be invoked from any component outside the class rather than just make the constructor private (as is the norm)? I would like to know what kind of extra benefit does this style endow over the usual private constructor style (if any)?

Comment: Usually I see the *private key* idiom is used for `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` in a class factory function (a static function, often named `Make` or `New` or `Create`).  Why?  Because (for now) it isn't possible to have a **private** constructor and have `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` a `friend`.  That may be fixed in a future C++.  The example shown is not a use case for the *private key* idiom.

Comment: Note that as this stands, you can use `A({})` to construct an instance of `A` from the outside

Comment: @Artyer I had tried passing in `0` etc. unsuccessfully but didn't realize that an empty value initialization works here. Definitely a major pitfall for this approach.